# How to deserialize soap response with multiref in .net?

Tags: xml-deserialization, soapfault

I am making a .net wcf client for java ws. But when I make a request, and response contains fault, it also contains **multiRef** section. So I get this exception:

> Server returned an invalid SOAP Fault.
>   End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope expected. Found element 'multiRef' from namespace ''

This is how response from server looks like (taken directly from network):

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>...</soapenv:Fault>

    <multiRef>...</multiRef>

   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there any way to configure my wcf client to deserialize that message right ? Or a possibility to get a raw response xml?

Comment: If you never find the solution you can always try to perform the request using HttWebRequest the problem is you will have to do the parsing manually that is easier said than done and you will need check the response for WebExceptions so it returns the response in error. Good luck.